# Summernote has uneditable inputs in modals with dialogsInBody

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog, summernote

I have one instance of summnernote in jQuery UI dialog. 
By default all summernote's modals look like this:

[image]

But when I remove `<div class="modal-backdrop  in"></div>`, I can write into all inputs in these modals:

[image]

Well, I've found a solution with **dialogsInBody**:

```
$('someTarget').summernote({
    dialogsInBody: true,
    ... //another options
});
```

But when I turn it on, all text inputs inside the summernote's modals **are uneditable**! I can interact with checkboxes and file inputs, even the cursor changes to "text", but I am not allowed to write anything into text inputs:

[image]

I've inspected, there aren't any blocks over them. And I can't find any extra styles to block inputs (e.g. like `pointer-events`).

What does exactly do option **dialogsInBody**? Why inputs aren't editable?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've resolved this problem by myself.

There are details:

1. In *summernote.js* there are such usage of **dialogsInBody**:

   ```
   var $container = options.dialogsInBody ? $(document.body) : $editor;
   ```

   Therefore modal window appends itself to body (instead summernote editor) when we set `{dialogsInBody:true}`. Nothing else.
2. Jquery UI Dialog has a behavior that blocks all text inputs outside of itself (see [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-_allowInteraction)). So when **summernote** is opened inside **ui-dialog** all of its modals has uneditable inputs.

My solution is to exclude all inputs in summernote modals from list of disallowed items. it required to override a dialog method **_allowInteraction**:

```
//fix problem that block inputs in modal dialog outside main UI Dialog

if ($.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction) {
    var originalAllowInteraction = $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction;
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(e) {
        var isInModal = $(e.target).closest('.modal-dialog').length > 0; 
        return isInModal || originalAllowInteraction(e);
    };
}
```